# What to do if an initialization surrounded by dispatch_once fails?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

A standard way to provide a shared instance of an Objective-C class is:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static MyClass shared;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [MyClass new];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

But what if the initialization fails and returns `nil`? Would it be `nil` forever? Shouldn't there be a `nil` test somewhere, followed by resetting `onceToken` (somehow) if needed?

Answer (score 3):

Resetting `onceToken` is not an option. The block should take whatever steps are necessary to ensure that, by the time it returns, initialization has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a singleton. If you cannot create the singleton, you have a serious problem. If it is just a hypothetical problem, ignore it. If your alloc/init could return nil, and it returns nil, what can you do except throwing the towel in the ring and tell your app to kill itself? Any reason why you think it might succeed later?